# Access and volume levels in Android

Tags: android, audio, volume

Is there a way in the standard SDK that I can access the different channels such as *Navigation Volume*, *Media Volume*, *Ringer Volume*? If so can I get the level it is at and set it?

Comment: Maybe it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924676/how-do-i-get-the-current-volume-amplitude-in-an-android-mediaplayer

Answer (score 3):

Use `AudioManager`. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Volume) demonstrating using the volumes for the audio streams.