# Animate Progressbar by getting the amplitude of mediaPlayer

Tags: android

Hi I've read some [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924676/how-do-i-get-the-current-volume-amplitude-in-an-android-mediaplayer) with same question but can't find the exact or I must say the answer I've been looking for. Well I just want to know how I can get the playback level of the audio file that is set on the mediaplayer. I already tried the  `int volume_level = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` but from what I see. I only get the current volume set on my device. Well what I want to achive is to add an animation that follows with level of my audio being played. Here's my code so far:

before the call of play audio method:

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

the playback method:

```
public void playAudio(String record_path) throws IOException{
        if(audioPlayer!=null && mpStatus == State.Paused){
            /*play from paused state*/
            audioPlayer.start();
            mpStatus = State.Playing;
        }
        else
        {
            /*play from start of recording*/
            setMediaPlayer(record_path);
            audioPlayer.start();
            mpStatus = State.Playing;
        }
    }
```

and the thread:

```
private class playBackRunnable extends Thread {
        final long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        public void run() {
            while(chk_play.isChecked()){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }

                final long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
                final String elapsed_time = util.getAsTime((int) elapsed);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int volume_level = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                        int amp = (int)(volume_level * 100.f)/100;
                        Log.v("Volume Level", String.valueOf(amp));

                        if(chk_play.isChecked()){
                            prog_volume.setProgress(amp);
                            //txt_rectime.setText(elapsed_time);

                            if(amp <= 40 ){
                                prog_volume.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_green));
                            }else if(amp <= 60){
                                prog_volume.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_yellow));
                            }else if(amp <= 80){
                                prog_volume.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_orange));
                            }else {
                                prog_volume.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_red));
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Added `audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` before audioPlayer.prepare() still not working.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Nope. But I think I might try doing this again next time. :D

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I know uses the Visualizer class. For convenience reason, I suggest using AudioCapture.java from [KitKat live wallpaper sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/MusicVisualization/+/android-4.4.2_r2/src/com/android/musicvis/AudioCapture.java), which add a data processing layer over Visualizer. The project linked above also gives some examples of uses, and here is how I use it in myself for JUnits tests :

```
private int getAudioOutputAmplitude(int durationInSeconds) throws InterruptedException {
    AudioCapture mAudioCapture = new AudioCapture(AudioCapture.TYPE_PCM, 1024);
    mAudioCapture.start();
    Thread.sleep(durationInSeconds * 1000);
    int [] mVizData;
    mVizData = mAudioCapture.getFormattedData(1, 1);
    mAudioCapture.release();
    int minValue = 0;
    int maxValue = 0;
    for (int value:mVizData){
        if (value<minValue){
            minValue = value;
        } else if (value>maxValue){
            maxValue = value;
        }
    }
    return maxValue-minValue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, @elgui! I also see the only solution is to use the Visualizer class. Thanks for help